# addEventListener only works when I use window infront of it

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to use a code when I press the space bar a shape appears and it disappears when I press it again. I'm trying to get the `addEventListener` to work with a sample:

```js
hello = document.querySelector('#Player');
```

with player being the id of the shape that I want to control. I declared `hello` above and initialized it in setup (I am using JavaScript), the `Player` id has also been initialized in HTML and given a shape in CSS. When I use

```js
hello.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  console.log(event.key)
})
```

nothing happens, but when I use

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  console.log(event.key)
})
```

it works. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: What type of element is referenced by *hello*? Is it able to receive keyboard events?

Comment: It's just a variable that I made. var hello;

Comment: You have `hello = document.querySelector('#Player');` That assigns something to *hello*. What is it?

Comment: `#Player{
    width:80%;
    height:100px;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:10%;
    border-radius: 15px;
}`

Comment: Ok, that's the CSS rule, where's the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

That's what should happen.

You can add the keypress event to the `window` or `document`.

And, if you add it to both, the window wins over for some reason – someone else might clarify this to both of us.

```js
const el = document.getElementById("el");
el.addEventListener("keypress", event => keyPressed(event, "blue"));
document.addEventListener("keypress", event => keyPressed(event, "green"));
window.addEventListener("keypress", event => keyPressed(event, "purple"));
function keyPressed(event, color) {
    if (event.key = " ")
        el.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
#el {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```

Comment: So what you're telling me is that keypressed can only be added to window and document and not to a variable I initialized? Thank you.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I wanted to thank him for giving me an answer. I was just going to use window instead of hello but I guess you can still use hello.

Comment: @Shino784 sorry for not clarifying that already but in your case it's best to add it to the window or document since they are focused on 100% of the time. What is focus exactly? It's the same to think about that you have an input field and you have it focused so you can type in it what you want. In conclusion to use keypress to my knowledge it has to be the window, the document or any other element that has focus I hope this answers it. and sorry again for not clarifying

Answer (score 0):

It is because by default `div` is not selectable. In order to make it selectable you need to use `tabindex` attribute on your `div`. It will make your `div` selectable.

```js
const hello = document.querySelector('#player');

hello.addEventListener("keypress", evt => {
  console.log(evt.key)
})
```

```html
<div id="player" tabindex="0">
  Player Shape
</div>
```

It will show a boundary around your `div` which can be remove by using css -

```
outline: none;
```

Comment: Hello, I have just tried this piece of code and nothing shows up in the console still. Thank you for the recommendation though

Comment: @Shino784 Have you clicked on the player before pressing keys? So that it becomes active?

Comment: Okay I just did and that works, thank you very much! But for the code I'm trying to do I would like it to appear and disappear by using the spacebar, would I always have to press on the shape first before I can do this?

Comment: @Shino784 Well, you try to apply the keypress event to the player, so it only triggers when the player is active. If you have a click event on a specific button I assume you expect it to only trigger when you click that button, not when you click anywhere else? Same applies to other events. If you want to be able to click everywhere, you need to attach it to the `window`.

Comment: Well not click, I would just like to press the spacebar and the shape appears, press the space bar and the shape disappears. Right now I'm just going bit by bit to get it to work and then add it into a statement for when the spacebar only is pressed.

Comment: @Shino784 You're misunderstanding my comment. The click was just an example. You want to show and hide a shape, but that doesn't mean that you have to also attach the event to that same shape. It's quite simple: If you want to be able to press space regardless of what element is active, then use `window`. If you want to only do something when the shape is active (is clicked on), then attach the event to the shape.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I made it out harder than it should be and I apologize. I simply used the keycode function, used if the keyCode ==32 then I make a variable `isPlaying` true and if i press it again it becomes false then I added an ifstatement to if it's true then the display for player would be block and if false would be none for CSS, thank you so much.